# "" inside URL - NGINX

Tags: nginx, unicode, url-rewriting, character

How is the globe-character embedded into the URL like WhatsApp Web did?
I can't find a way to add the  character into the nginx configuration and also google is not giving me a clue.

How they added that awesome character?

Comment: Have you tried using `xn--wg8h` or `%F0%9F%8C%90` in place of the   character? The former works if it's part of the domain AFAIK, if in the path the latter is what you'll want

Comment: Placeing %F0%9F%8C%90 and the other one as location /%F0%9F%8C%90? Or how do you mean that

Comment: Yeah, you could try that. I did some testing there didn't have much success sorry

Comment: Did it and had the same result... Let's try it with the rewrite module. Should work then.